# If I include Geo Targeted content in a website, how could I also change that content when a visitor selects a location page?

Tags: web, location, target, geo

I want to change the phone number that appears in the header of the website, based on the users location. I believe I can get that taken care of with the Geo Targetly service. However, the website will have multiple location pages. When the user visits one of those locations, I would want the phone number from that location page to override the geo targeted content. An example is how they are doing it on this website: https://www.benjaminfranklinplumbing.com/

I am not sure how to change the phone number for the entire website based on which location they choose. I would appreciate any assistance.